# How to find out if an android device is using TEE?

Tags: drm, tee

I am new to [Trusty TEE](https://source.android.com/security/trusty) OS. Is there any way to find out if an Android Device uses such an OS without rooting the device ?

AFAIK there, DRM (Digital Rights Management) is the most widely used application of Trusty OS. Some examples for DRM frameworks are Widevine/PlayReady/ClearKey.

Does it mean that if any of these frameworks are present in the Android device, it is safe to assume that there is an underlying Trusty TEE OS in use ?

Thanks

Comment: Trusty is a kinda reference implementation of a TEE OS. But many OEMs have been using their own closed source implementations including QSEE, Kinibi, TEEGris, iTrustee etc. I don't think you'll find a clue about the underlying implementation on a non-rooted device. One possibility is that the name of the HAL(s) (binary blobs) process (usually an `init` service) interacting with TEE hardware may include some hint. On a rooted device, however, there are higher chances of getting a hint e.g. from the name or hexdump of some TEE-related partition. Even running `strings` on such partition may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is an android 8+ device, TEE is a mandatory requirement for OEMs to obtain Google Mobile Services (GMS) licensing for devices that have Google apps pre-installed.

In Settings > Security > Advanced > Encryption & credentials > (CREDENTIAL STORAGE) Storage type > **Hardware-backed**

If it says hardware backed then TEE is present.

Programmatically, you can use `isInsideSecureHardware()` which returns true if the key resides inside TEE or SE.

If you want to explicitly verify if it's SE, use `setIsStrongBoxBacked` on the `keyGenParameterSpecBuilder`, key generation will fail with a `StrongBoxUnavailableException` if StrongBox is not supported.

Qualcomm Snapdragon and Samsung Exynos SoCs contain integrated TEE and they throw StrongBox unavailable exception but returns true for isInsideSecureHardware. Google's Titan M chip and Samsung Knox chip are discrete TEEs (called strongbox) that contains SE inside.

Comment: Well explained but it answers *"How to find out if an Android device is using TEE?"* (or SE). The question is *"How to find out if an Android device is using Trusty TEE OS?"* TEE is not always Trusty, it's OEM's choice.

Comment: Right. I thought OP meant TEE only and might be calling Trusty TEE because of the title on android source. I made the same mistake few years back when I first read TEE support in android. Open to edits.

Comment: yes I actually meant only TEE. thanks for pointing it out. I have posted a new related question here https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233749/how-to-determine-if-an-android-application-uses-trusted-execution-environment-t maybe you could suggest something here as well ?