# How to determine if an android application uses Trusted Execution Environment (TEE) and Secure Element (SE)?

Tags: security, drm, tee

I have gone through questions [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61225795/how-to-check-whether-android-phone-supports-tee/64422042#64422042) and [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39957052/does-the-android-keystore-make-use-of-the-trusted-execution-environment-tee-an). But still I have an additional question.

How do we find out that an android application uses Trusted Execution Environment (TEE) and Secure Element (SE). Particularly a hardware backed environment.

Thanks

Comment: Apps usually don't use TEE or SE directly. They aren't privileged enough to access underlying hardware resources. Instead they are using system APIs (e.g. [Android keystore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore)) or libraries (e.g. [androidx.security](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/security)) which subsequently use TEE if the device supports. So ask the developer or get the source code and find if the app is using any such API.

Comment: @IrfanLatif To my knowledge apps can use the TEE, however this seems to require additional negotiations in the background between the app developer and the device manufacturer so not everybody can do so. For example the [Netflix app is known to use the TEE](https://www.securetechalliance.org/wp-content/uploads/TEE-101-White-Paper-FINAL2-April-2018.pdf). May be this is the reason that devices need to be certified for Netflix HD playback?

Comment: @Robert yes definitely OEMs and ROM developers can access the hardware resources directly using low level APIs. And also they are sure if the device [supports](https://source.android.com/security/keystore) TEE or not. But normal apps cannot. Though they can query if the device supports TEE. Android Keystore, for instance, uses hardware-backed storage if the device supports, otherwise it silently uses software-backed storage. So even if we figure out that the app is using Keystore APIs, we cannot say for sure if it's using TEE. It depends on the device it's running on.

Comment: @Robert Not in android. Google even recommends OEM against exposing API which can directly talk with kernel. Android has **HAL**s that allow android framework to talk with the kernel. To use TEE, apps call `AndroidKeystore` Provider API which talks to **Keymaster HAL** which talks to **kernel** which talks to **TEE**.

Comment: Any app that uses **KeyStore** and **KeyPairGenerator** or **KeyGenerator** classes along with the **AndroidKeyStore** provider and **KeyChain** API makes use of TEE. AndroidKeyStore provider API handles communication with whatever keystore is available on that device.